# select boxes with like info disabled on selection in all dropdowns

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 3 select boxes, all populated with the same data.  Using jquery I would like to either a) disable the same options or b) remove the same options from the other two select boxes.  I have posted the html below. You will notice I already have some headers within the select disabled, and those need to stay that way.  This needs to work no matter which select box the user starts with. So if select three option 2 is picked, select 1 and 2 are disabled.

The jquery has been eluding me for hours.

edit:  I forgot to add a couple things. If you change your selection, I need it to enable the previously selected option. Also, I would like the first choice ( -- ) in each of the lists to always be available.

```
<fieldset class="fields1">
        <dl>
            <dt><label for="char_cs">test:</label></dt>
            <dd>
                <select id="char_cs1" name="char_cs1" class="char_cs">
                    <option value="">--</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">header 1</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">header 2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">header 3</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dd>
                <select id="char_cs2" name="char_cs2" class="char_cs">
                    <option value="">--</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">header 1</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">header 2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">header 3</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dd>
                <select id="char_cs3" name="char_cs3" class="char_cs">
                    <option value="">--</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">header 1</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">header 2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">header 3</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.char_cs').change(function() {
    var ary = new Array();
    $('.char_cs option:selected').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            ary.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $('.char_cs option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf('header')!=0) {
            if ($.inArray($(this).val(), ary) > -1) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/53DDt/2/)**.

Comment: Thanks, almost there with this one. If you change your choices it never enables the old choice.

Comment: Well you never said that in your question now did you? :P Give me a minute and I'll see if I can update.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot about a couple things when I was writing out that question.   I've edited it to reflect the corrections.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The fiddle works perfect.  When I'm home from work I'll implement it. Thanks

Comment: When placed into a form and submitted.  It does not send the values associated with each selection.  I assume that is because it's disabling the choice on all 3 selects, not just the two 'other' selects. Anyway around that? Other then the submitting it works great. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how you're collecting the data and submitting it, but it looks like it should be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/53DDt/26/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sDeCW/2/).
I've made it so that it doesn't disable the entry in the active select.  Also once you change the option selected, it becomes available in the other selects.

```
$(".char_cs").change(function(){
    $("select>option:not([value^=header])").removeAttr("disabled");
    $(".char_cs").each(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").substring(7);
        var val = $(this).val();
        $(".char_cs:not([id=char_cs"+id+"])>option(:not[value=--],[value="+val+"])").attr("disabled","disabled");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Nice, it drops the 'disabled' on the headers after you start selecting options though.